# The Odin Project TDD solution

Tags: javascript, tdd

I'm doing the Odin Project. I'm learning the TDD bit at the moment. I need help passing the first test for 'helloWorld.'

JS file:

```
const helloWorld = function() {
  return ''
}

module.exports = helloWorld
```

.spec file:

```
const helloWorld = require('./helloWorld');

describe('Hello World', function() {
  it('says hello world', function() {
    expect(helloWorld()).toEqual('Hello, World!');
  });
});
```

The test is not passing because the function is returning an empty string when it is suppose to return "Hello, World!" i go into the JS file and make the changes and save.

```
const helloWorld = function() {
  return 'Hello, World!'
}

module.exports = helloWorld
```

I run 'jasmine helloWorld.spec.js' command in the terminal. The terminal returns the following message:

```
Failures:
1) Hello World says hello world
  Message:
    Expected '' to equal 'Hello, World!'.
  Stack:
    Error: Expected '' to equal 'Hello, World!'.
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Right now your function returns an empty string `''` instead make it return the string your test is expecting - `'Hello, World!'`:

```js
const helloWorld = function() {
  return 'Hello, World!'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should write `Hello, World!` instead of `hello world`. The function is character sensitive.